# How to record test cases for android with Appium?

Tags: android, appium, record

I am integrating Appium for automation testing in Android, and successfully run it. Now the problem is recording test cases, I did not find proper steps to record.

I have integrated Appium from below link
http://qaautomated.blogspot.in/2016/01/setting-up-appium-with-android-studio.html

Getting error pop up if i try to record
Error performing tap action: unexpected error, missing parameters:["selector"]

Anyone can guide?

Comment: how are you trying to record? meaning when are you facing this error `Error performing tap action: unexpected error, missing parameters:["selector"]`

Comment: I click on the Inspector icon on the Appium panel, new window opens with screenshot of my application activity which is currently open, when i click on the Tap button present at the bottom of that new opened window, I am getting this error.

Comment: prior to selecting `tap`, have you selected an element on the inspector which has the property `clickable : true` ?

Comment: @nullpointer, There is screenshot showing on the inspector, and i can see the element location and id in the detail window, but it dont write test cases for us like monkeytalk do, i didnt find any provision to record the test cases in the Appium, here i manually have to write it down.

Comment: Hey Pratibha,  https://discuss.appium.io/

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that Appium is not used for recording test cases and you cannot use it for that. But instead is used more as a server and as a framework.
You can inspect elements with the desktop version and also use other tools that they provide like TestObject and SauceLabs, but you cannot record test cases with it.
You have to use an IDE like Appium Studio which has the functionality to record test cases but only on real devices, it will not run on an emulator.

I have found Espresso useful for recording test cases for android. It is really easy to install, record and play your test cases with it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Launch the appium inspector by clicking the inspector button:

Step 2: Set the APK / IPA file path (application file path) as shown below:

Step 3 : Click on Start Session, now you will be navigated to Recorder window:

Click the application UI and perform required action “Selected Element” Tab ie, Tap, SendKeys for entering the text etc.

Selected UI Elements will get exported to Recorder tab after recording the UI Elements of all the elements we can export the Java file.